# Script generated spreadsheets appear in 'My Projects' even if they have no script attached

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script, attached to a spreadsheet, which creates a number of other spreadsheets by copying a template spreadsheet and populating it.  The template does not have any script associated with it, but the copies all seem to appear in the 'My Projects' list, making it hard to find legitimate scripts.

The spreadsheet 'scripts' appear in the list, even though they have no actual script attached to them.  I can delete them from 'My Projects' without affecting the spreadsheets.

Is there a way to prevent these non-scripts appearing in 'My Projects', or a faster way of removing them than deleting them individually by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it myself and couldn't reproduce that behavior. I copied a spreadsheet (using Apps Script) without any bound script attached, and nothing was generated. However, there's a catch! If you click on `Extensions` > `Apps Script`, a project gets attached to the sheet automatically, even if said project is left blank, and whenever you make a copy of that file, it will copy that blank script as well.

Copying spreadsheets without a GAS project
[image: Without Apps Script project bounded]

Copying a spreadsheet with a blank GAS project (after just clicking on `Extensions` > `App Script`)

[image: With Apps Script project attached]

#### Quick fix

You can try deleting the GAS project from the template, by following these steps

1. open the template spreadsheet
2. Go to Extensions > Apps Script
3. Click on 'Overview'
   [image: Project settings]
4. And then, Trash the project.
   [image]
   That should address the issue and allow you to continue copying your template without generating new scripts (just make sure not to access to Apps script again from that file)

#### References

- [Container-bound Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)

Comment: Thank you Milagro, that is the answer.  I deleted the empty scripts from the template sheets and did not get any new entries in 'My Projects' today